# msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed global catalog replication

Tags: active-directory

I am currently trying to find out AD users password expiry date.

Using the methods described on numerous pages for e.g. [here](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/AD%20Determining%20Password%20Expiration) work fine until a user or group in AD is using a fine grained password policy that does not follow the users domain password policy.

I found a property called msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed that figures that all out without trying to do any calculations.

This works well, until we are using a global catalog since this property is not replicated by default. When I attempting to replicate the msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed property in my global catalog, I get the following error:

[image: replication error]

Is there anyway to replicate this property or is something wrong with my setup that is not allowing me to replicate this property? Is there a better way to calculate user password expiry to take into account the fine grained password policy?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you can't. I can't find any authoritative documentation saying it is not possible, but here are the reasons I think it's not possible:

1. The attribute is constructed, meaning it's not stored, but it's calculated at the time you ask for it.
2. The date depends on the policy on the domain, thus the server returning the data needs to know the policy on the domain of the user.
3. Since a GC may not be on the domain of the user you find, it may not have the information needed to be able to calculate the value.

As a workaround, you can just rebind to a DC to get the value. You didn't say which language you're working with, but usually you can take the path of the object you found, which will start with "GC://", and just replace that with "LDAP://". Then grab the `msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed` value.

Comment: We are using c# to retrieve user properties. Based on what you are suggesting with regards to using LDAP instead of GC, If I can connect to the Global Catalog, do the credentials I have guarantee that I can directly connect to the user to retrieve their properties?

Comment: Yes, because the GC looks at the whole AD forest and each domain in the forest, by definition, must trust each other.

Comment: You might run into complications if the computer you are running this from is not joined to a domain in the same forest, or if you have weird firewall rules that only allow hitting the GC port (3268) but not the LDAP port (389).